# Automatic scroll javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I want the viewer to scroll automatic to a section, when he scrolls.
So that the viewer can't see a screen between two sections (each section has the height of 1 vh). Only the last section #contact has not the size of 1 vh.

I have a script working, but there has to be a better and cleaner way. This code works in Chrome, but I have to wait a while untill I can scroll again. It is not working with Firefox

Could someone tell me how it can be done properly or tell me if there is a plug-in for this? I can't find anything!

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
var height = $(window).scrollTop();
var vheight = $(window).height();

if (height >= lastScrollTop){

if(height > 1  && height < 100) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#mission').offset().top
    }, 500); 
}


if(height > 2 * vheight + 1 && height < 2 * vheight + 200){
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#about').offset().top
    }, 500); 
}

if(height > 3 * vheight + 1 && height < 3 * vheight + 200){
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#contact').offset().top
    }, 500); 
    $('#scrollAbout').hide(500);

}

} else {
  var docheight = $(document).height(); 
  docheight -= vwheight;

  if(height < vheight - 1  && height > vheight - 200) {
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#home').offset().top
      }, 500); 
  }



  if(height < 3 * vheight - 1 && height >  3 *vheight - 200){
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#case-studies').offset().top
      }, 500); 
  }

  if(height < docheight - 1 && height > docheight - 100){
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#about').offset().top
      }, 500); 
      $('#scrollAbout').show(500);

  }


}
lastScrollTop = height;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for something like the [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) library.

More specifically [this scenario](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/autoHeight.html), where the last section is not full screen but yet, it still being scrolled automatically. 
You can achieve that by using the `fp-auto-height` class as detailed [in the documentation](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#creating-smaller-or-bigger-sections).

[Here's a codepen](http://codepen.io/alvarotrigo/pen/BKjRYm)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can then accept (green tick) and upvote the answer to help and orientate other people who might end up in this same question too!